# np.dot in NumPy printing the transpose of what should be expected

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm really new to Python and am wondering why this is printing the opposite of expected. A (7x4)(4x2)(2x1) multiplication should result in a 7x1 column vector.

```
import numpy as np

nutrition = np.array([[61, 100, 7, 2.2, 1, 7, 215],
                      [156, 340, 18, 7, 44, 5, 0],
                      [19, 110, 9, 3.3, 0, 6, 16],
                      [27, 60, 2, 0.5, 8, 2, 16]])

meals = np.array([[2, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 1, 1]]

M = np.array([40, 10])


print(np.dot(nutrition.T, np.dot(meals.T, M)))
```

Instead, it is printing a 1x7 row vector:

```
[13140. 26700.  1570.   564.  2360.   890. 17520.]
```

Any explanation or problems to look into would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array `M` is of shape `(2,)` and **NOT** `(2,1)`:

```
print(M.shape)
(2,)
```

Hence, the output shape is `(7,)` and **NOT** `(7,1)`. Which makes it a 1-D array represented in a single row:

```
print(np.dot(nutrition.T, np.dot(meals.T, M)).shape)
(7,)
```

If you want a `(7,1)` output, simply reshape your `M` to `(2,1)`:

```
M = M.reshape(-1,1)
#[[40]
# [10]]
```

And output would be:

```
[[13140.]
 [26700.]
 [ 1570.]
 [  564.]
 [ 2360.]
 [  890.]
 [17520.]]
```

Comment: +1 Alternatively, you could define M as `M = np.array([[40], [10]])` to give it shape (2,1) as expected.

Comment: @tiberius Exactly. Thank you.

Comment: May be worth being explicit here (obviously you know this, but maybe not everyone does), that a shape `(2,)` is _not_ any kind of shorthand for `(2,1)`.  It is purely and simply that the syntax for writing a size-1 tuple requires an extra comma in order to distinguish it from the expression `(2)`.